# ¿Cómo guardar ciertos valores de una lista en otra lista anidada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Tengo `iList` la cual es una lista, lo que quiero lograr es hacer un recorrido para `iList` de manera que si se encuentra la palabra `Final`, todo lo que esta después sea alojado en una nueva sublista, de manera que al final al mostrar `fList` en consola el resultado sea:

```
fList = [["carro1", "carro2", "carro3"], ["Avion1", "Avion2"]]
```

Estuve intentando hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
fList = []
contador = 0
iList = ["carro1", "carro2", "carro3", "Final", "Avion1", "Avion2", "Final"]

for i in range(len(iList)):
    if iList[i] != "Final":
        fList[contador].append(iList[i])
    else:
        contador = contador + 1

print(fList)
```

Pero solo obtuve en consola:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Por lo que si alguien pudiera ayudarme le estaré agradecido.

Comment: El ultimo "final" de tu lista tiene que estar si o si o se lo puede eliminar?

Comment: El ultimo final si tiene que estar si o si :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explicación

Tu problema se debe a que en ningún momento creas las sublistas que necesitas. Tu lista principal siempre está vacía. Por lo tanto cuando intentas agregar "carro1" a la sublista (item 0) resulta que la supuesta sublista no existe, la lista no tiene items. Por lo tanto tira error.

## Solución

```
# Inicio con una unica sublista dentro de fList
# Así cuando ingreso los primeros elementos antes del primer "Final", existe una sublista en los cuales agregarlos.
fList = [[]]
contador = 0
iList = ["carro1", "carro2", "carro3", "Final", "Avion1", "Avion2", "Final"]

for i in range(len(iList)):
    if iList[i] != "Final":
        fList[contador].append(iList[i])
    else:
        # Cada vez que la palabra "Final" aparezca, agrego una nueva sublista al final de la lista.
        fList.append([])
        contador = contador + 1

#Elimino el ultimo item la lista, ya que será una sublista vacia
fList = fList[:-1]

print(fList)
```

Comment: Funciono de maravilla, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si los "Final" son los separadores de las sublistas, puedes buscar todos los índices de la palabra "Final" para hacer los slices desde `start(0)` hasta `indice("Final")`. Una vez que se hace el slice, se asigna `start = indice(Final)+1` y se busca el siguiente "Final". Cuando ya no se encuentre ninguno, es porque llegó al final del ciclo y se rompe.

```
fList = []
start = 0
while True:
    if "Final" in iList[start:]:
        idx = iList.index("Final", start)
        fList.append(iList[start:idx])
        start = idx + 1
    else:
        break

print(fList)
```

Pusiste que la lista termina SI o SI con `"Final"`. Pero en caso de que no sea así, solo tienes que agregar un `elif` que se ejecutará en la última ronda, cuando no encuentre un "Final", pero que la longitud de la sublista es mayor que cero.

```
    elif len(iList[start:]) > 0:
        fList.append(iList[start:])
        break
```